# Trouble setting up libraries imported from github

Tags: python, github, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to clone a repo to my machine to test changes for a pull request.

The repo in question is a clone of pytorch, and I want to add something to one of the files to fix an issue. I figured how to clone the repo, but I can't figure out how to import the pytorch libraries when I write a test file that contains something like:

```
import torch
x = torch.rand(5, 3)
print(x)
```

Where am I supposed to create a test.py file? How do I add pytorch (specifically my cloned version of pytorch) to the list of dependencies for Python to run with? I tried just creating a test.py file at the same level as the cloned repo, but i get the error message
"no module named torch.version". I am using VS code.

I'm new to using git and not extremely familiar with the structure of libraries like this. I tried looking through github, stack overflow and the pytorch docs but was unable to find an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your current selected interpreter doesn't contain pytorch, then before `import torch`, add the following code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("\the folder that contains pytorch\")
```

Please have a try.